# Lebesgue Stiltjes measure as sum of lebesgue measure and countable sum of Dirac measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $ F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a montonic increasing right-sided continuous function.
Denote the Borel-Sigma-Algebra as $B$. And define $\mu: B \to [0, \infty]$ as $\mu((a,b)) := F(b) - F(a)  $ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$.
I want to show that, if F is on every finite interval piecewise continuously differentiable, and $x_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\delta_{x_k} $ denote the Dirac-Measure.
Then we can write:
$ \mu(A)= \int_A f d\lambda + \sum_{k=1} ^\infty g_k\delta_{x_k}(A)$ for all $A \in B$, such that $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty)$ is measurable and $g_k \in [0,\infty)$.

I am not sure what could be meant with piecewise continuously differentiable on every finite interval. I am also struggling to prove it for any Borel set, since the measure $\mu$ is only defined on intervals. I am also wondering if the condition of piecewise continuously differentiable on every finite interval is really necessary. If it is necessary, I would be very glad if someone could show me a counterexample.

Comment: Cantor function is a counter-example  if you drop differentiability hypothesis. Also, the second term $\sum_{k=1} ^\infty g_k\delta_{x_k}(A)$ seems unnecessary since $F$ is assumed to be continuous.

Comment: @geetha290krm could you elaborate why the Cantor function is a counter-example? And I actually do think that the second term is necessary, since $F$ is only right-sided continuous, meaning that it can still have jumps

Comment: Sorry, I thought your function was continuous.  Cantor function is continuous, there is no second term, and your formula for $\mu$ would make it absolutely continuous, whereas $\mu$ is singular for the Cantor function.

Comment: This result is non-trivial even if $F$ is differentiable at every point. This case has been answered on MSE earlier.

Comment: Do you happen to know where the earlier MSE entry is? I could not find it.

Comment: It is a theorem in Rudin's RCA.